# How to find find value in table cell value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table html code that comes from out source via ajax like this:

```
<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">City</td>
        <td class="red">xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country</td>
        <td class="red">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date</td>
        <td class="red">05.10.2017</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Category</td>
        <td class="red">This is category</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get value of `country` value in this html. Jquery nth-child can find but I could not find. I find `nht tr` item but can not find value ("abc") of country.

Comment: why don't you give it a class or an id as reference instead of just "red" ?

Comment: html code comes from outside, I did not create it.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with it, but if you want to get the second `td` of a `tr` that contains `Country`, use the following `$("table tr:contains(Country) td:eq(1)").text()`

**Demo**

```js
var text = $("table tr:contains(Country) td:eq(1)").text();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">City</td>
        <td class="red">xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country</td>
        <td class="red">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date</td>
        <td class="red">05.10.2017</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Category</td>
        <td class="red">This is category</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let country = document.querySelectorAll("tr")[1].querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;

 document.querySelectorAll("tr")[1] (second tr)
 .querySelectorAll("td")[1] (second td in second tr)
 .innerText (gets value)
```

Comment: You should always aim to add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about following selector:

```
  $( "table.stripped tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)" ).val();
```

Comment: This answer is not flexible, it only works if the country is always the second child.

Answer (score 0):

The only real reference point besides `nth-child` is your text headings.

Since this is the case we can just look through your table cells for the heading *Date* and then get the text from the following cell (that cell's index + 1).

It should be pointed out that this is less than ideal. This solution, like every other one we can offer given the circumstances, can very easily be defeated if mark-up changes in the future. Just something to keep in mind, though I do understand that sometimes you have no choice.

```js
$("td").each(function(ind, ele) {
if(ele.textContent === "Date"){
console.log("date is", $("td").eq(ind+1).text() );
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">City</td>
        <td class="red">xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country</td>
        <td class="red">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date</td>
        <td class="red">05.10.2017</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Category</td>
        <td class="red">This is category</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code: http://tpcg.io/Vy9IwJ

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".stripped td").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
        if ($(entry).text()=='Country') {
            $('#result').html( $('#result').html()+'Country: '+$(entry).next().text() );
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="result">
</div> 
<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">City</td>
        <td class="red">xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country</td>
        <td class="red">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date</td>
        <td class="red">05.10.2017</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="stripped">
    <tr class="red">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Category</td>
        <td class="red">This is category</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```